Kutty Components (tailwindcss) Firebase Host
Could someone explain why kutty (tailwindcss component library) is in localhost but when I host the site with Firebase it doesn't work?Here is an image of the files if it can help
And here is an image of what happens:
enter image description here
I've tried to check for dependencies and other things suggested by ChatGPT but nothing This problem has been going on for days now.
